# use local yum repository created by createrepo in other servers

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rpm, yum

Is there a way to use the local repository created by createrepo on one redhat box in the other redhat boxes?

```
 createrepo folder
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, please see the [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to expose it over http (or ftp) on that first box.

Or you can periodically sync it with rsync.